# Is it possible to change the entire background of Gazebo white or transparent?

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello friends, I am trying to get some nice screenshots of my model, but I didn't want them to have a background.  It would really make my paper pop if I could get the entire background of the empty Gazebo world I am using to be white instead of that standard gray.

I am sure this has been asked but I am struggling to find exactly what I am looking for....any help is greatly appreciated.

M

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25367/is-it-possible-to-change-the-entire-background-of-gazebo-white-or-transparent?/) by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/27016/matthewmarkey/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Add this description to your world file.

```
<scene>
  <ambient>1 1 1 1</ambient>
  <background>1 1 1 1</background>
  <shadows>0</shadows>
</scene>
```

For the full specification, see [here](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.7&elem=scene).

You could optionally try to play with the sun (see [here](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/models/sun/model.sdf)).

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/27016/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-06-24**:
Thanks for this! I got the background to go white, now I just need to get the "working area" (grid area) to also be white. It is currently gray...

EDIT: I think I have gotten something that is more then appropriate for my application.  Thanks a bunch for the help @nlamprian